# Wordpress Ajax call returns empty

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have a trouble with wordpress ajax call.

Action for admin-ajax.php has been defined correctly.
It returns correct result when user logged in, but it returns empty when user didn't log in.
Here is code for it.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_thwepo_calculate_extra_cost', array($this, 'wp_ajax_action_calculate_extra_cost_handler'), 10);
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_thwepo_calculate_extra_cost', array($this, 'wp_ajax_action_calculate_extra_cost_handler'), 10);

public function wp_ajax_action_calculate_extra_cost_handler() {
    $return = array(
        'code' => 'E001',
        'message' => ''
    );
    echo json_encode($return);
    exit;
}
```

And here is javascript code.

```
var data = {
    action: "thwepo_calculate_extra_cost",
    price_info: JSON.stringify(requestData)
};
currRequest = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: args.ajax_url,
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function() {
        null != currRequest && currRequest.abort()
    },
    success: function(rslt) {
        if ("E000" === rslt.code) {
            var result = rslt.result;
            result && display_new_price(args, result.display_price, isVariableProduct)
        } else "E002" === rslt.code && display_new_price(args, rslt.result, isVariableProduct)
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Here is screenshot of ajax call.

[image: ajax call]

[image: ajax call empty result]

It returns correct result when page loaded first time.
But when select option (i.e. Classes), it returns empty.
Why is this happened?

Is there anyone who have any idea?
Please let me know if needed any other information.

Page url is https://www.ivybound.net/classes/isee-prep-middle-level/

It can be checked by selecting "What do you need?" select option.

Comment: What are you using the `else "E002" === rslt.code && display_new_price(args, rslt.result, isVariableProduct)` for? It seems like this should be an `else if () { }` or at least add the opening `{` after `else`

Comment: This is a not problem, it is same as else if ( "E002" === rslt.code) { display_new_price(...)}, Main problem is rslt = "".  Wordpress returns $return = array(
        'code' => 'E001',        'message' => ''    ), but ajax call returns ""

Comment: I'm not seeing any error when I make selections. Console looks good and so does the XHR calls.